# Verify hash of plaintext through ciphertext

Tags: encryption, hash

Suppose that Alice runs a paid archival service.

1. Bob wants to download a well-known plaintext `M` with hash `H(M)` from Alice by sending her the hash.
2. Alice does not want to send `M` to Bob without Bob paying and Bob does not want to pay unless Alice sends him the real thing.
   Thus, Alice encrypts `M` with some temporary key `K` into: `E(M, K)` and sends that to Bob alongs with `H(K)`.
3. Bob checks that `E(M, K)` is indeed `M` encrypted with `K`, knowing only `{E(M, K), H(K), H(M)}`.

Is step 3 possible under some crypto system?

Comment: You probably need some form of zero knowledge proofs to do this.

Comment: I can imagine something like that using smart contracts on a blockchain... (_i.e._ changing steps 2 and 3 completely, but ending up with a way to ensure both delivery of the good and of the money to both receivers, without requiring a trusted third party.) This would prove useful to [deal with ransomware](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2017/02/28/the-future-of-ransomware/), imho.

Comment: @Lery Can you share how it is done? I already read that fair exchange is impossible without a trusted third party but my case does not seem to fit the description. `M` is no secret, it just takes resources to store and retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

Answering in a pragmatic way (it might help, depending on the background of the question):

Even if step 3 is possible, it does not matter, since this will not add any additional security value.

Because: Bob still has to trust Alice that she will send him `K` in case that he pays the money. So Bob could also simply trust Alice, that she has already send him the correct encrypted text `E(M, K)` in the first place.

Comment: Well, this might not necessarily be the case, it all depends on the way you send the money...  If the money is sent using a way which delivers it conditionally on `K` being correct, then Bob could send it... (But then how do you deal with dishonest Bobs? Well, the validity of `K` should be checked without having to trust him.) That's a nice problem to deal with. And there certainly are multiple ways around it.

Comment: Bob can sign a contract saying: "I pay the person who puts `K` (or rather: something that hashes to `H(K)`) here and sign it". That is not my big concern for now. The contract is also much smaller compared to `M` so they can even use  some trusted third party to settle.